# how to get result data from aws internal callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get aws appconfig data with js.

I studied about Js' callback, but it is too difficult to apply it to my work.
I think it's very different from my development language, Python.

```js
appconfigdata.startConfigurationSession(
    params_develop,
    function(err, data) {
        appconfigdata.getLatestConfiguration(
            {
            ConfigurationToken: data.InitialConfigurationToken,
            },
            function (err, data) {
                configuration = data['Configuration'].toString();
                console.log(configuration);
            });
    }
);
```

`data` of function in `startConfigurationSession` has `InitialConfigurationToken` value. I want to save `configuration` as variable.

**`data` of function in `getLatestConfiguration` has `Configuration` data that I want to get as `var response`.**

```js
/* not work */
var token = appconfigdata.startConfigurationSession(
    params_develop,
    function(err, data) {
        return data;
    }
);
```

`token` doesn't have `InitialConfigurationToken` value in this code.
So I can't get `Configuration` data as below.

```js
/* not work */
var response = appconfig.getLatestConfiguration(
    {ConfigurationToken: token.InitialConfigurationToken},
    function (err, data){
        return data['Configuration'].tostring();
    }
);
```

I don't know how to configure `async, await` because it's composed of built-in functions of functions.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the functions `requestToken` and `requestConfig` as normal function,

and called this function with `const`, `await` in `async` function. So it worked!

```js
function requestToken(params) {
    var request = _appconfigdata.startConfigurationSession(
        {
            ApplicationIdentifier: params.application_id,
            ConfigurationProfileIdentifier: params.configuration_id,
            EnvironmentIdentifier: params.environment_id,
        },
        function (err, data) {
        }
    );
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        request.on('success', resolve);
    });
}

function requestConfig(token){
    var request = _appconfigdata.getLatestConfiguration(
        {
            ConfigurationToken: token['InitialConfigurationToken']
        },
        function (err, data) {
        }
    );
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        request.on('success', resolve);
    });
}

async function get_config(params){
    const res_token = await requestToken(params);
    const res_config = await requestConfig(JSON.parse(res_token.httpResponse.body.toString()));
    return JSON.parse(res_config.httpResponse.body.toString());
}
```